# How to develop a secured Node.js WebApp with secured REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, passport.js, json-web-token

Is it a good practice to create `Express/Passport` WebApp for web users AND protected REST API with `jsonwebtoken` authorization in one project?

I have now a WebApp, `local-passport` login and some protected endpoints with HTML views. I would be able to add `passport-local` unprotected REST endpoints with `jsonwebtoken` protection but using two different authentication options seems like a bad practice.

This is my first Node.js project so I can't tell. Isn't there a better way how to create what I'm trying to create?